# Apex AggregateResult in Managed Packages

Tags: apex, soql, aggregateresult

When doing database aggregations in Apex and SOQL, we'd normally do something like this;

```java
        List<AggregateResult> prodsWithPositiveQuantityRem = [
            SELECT Product_Family__c, SUM(Quantity_Remaining__c) qtyRemaining
            FROM Product2 WHERE Quantity_Remaining__c > 0
            GROUP BY Product_Family__c];

        for(AggregateResult aggr: prodsWithPositiveQuantityRem) {
            System.debug(aggr.get('Product_Family__c'));
        }
```

Would there be need to worry about the namespace when accessing `aggr.get('Product_Family__c')` in managed packages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We learned that namespaces is really needed in few scenarios, so its better to be consistent and safe than spending time with creation of version to test namespace issues.

`Product2.Product_Family__c` would give the API name with namespace of the field, you could use that:

```java
List<AggregateResult> prodsWithPositiveQuantityRem = [
    SELECT Product_Family__c, SUM(Quantity_Remaining__c) qtyRemaining
    FROM Product2 WHERE Quantity_Remaining__c > 0
    GROUP BY Product_Family__c];

for(AggregateResult aggr: prodsWithPositiveQuantityRem) {
    System.debug(aggr.get('' + Product2.Product_Family__c));
}
```